# Symfony2 grouped form items

Tags: forms, symfony

I really need your help creating a form. I have **entity** with `$id`, `$name` and `$items` properties. `$items` is manyToMany relation. Then I have two other entities **group** and **item**. Both have `$id` and `$name` properties. **group** and **entity** have relation to **item**. Something like this:

```
Group 1                 Entity 1
 |- Item 1               |- Item 1
 '- Item 2               |- Item 2
                         '- Item 3

Group 2                 Entity 2
 |- Item 3               |- Item 2
 '- Item 4               |- Item 3
                         '- Item 4
```

What's the best way to create a form for **entity** with grouped items? Like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------
Group 1
 ☑ Item 1              ☑ Item 2
----------------------------------------------------
Group 2
 ☑ Item 3              ☑ Item 4
```

Tried to google, but, to be honest, I've no idea where to start :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok... So I found out, that `group_by` is used to get *optgroup*'s in `<select>`. My `EntityType` has:

```
$builder->add('item', 'entity' array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Item',
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'group_by' => 'group.name',
);
```

In my template:

```
{% form_theme form 'MyBundle::form_theme.html.twig' %}
{{ form_widget(form.item) }}
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

In my form theme I just tried to replicate `choice_widget_collapsed`, but there are some differences (eg.: checking if value is checked). I don't know if it's the best way to do so, but it works for me. Maybe because I'm using just `item` entity selection and no other input fields.
My form theme:

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% set options = choices %}
        {{ block('choice_widget_expanded_options') }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}

{% block choice_widget_expanded_options %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
        {% if choice is iterable %}
            <fieldset>
                <legend>{{ group_label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</legend>
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{ block('choice_widget_expanded_options') }}
            </fieldset>
        {% else %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ full_name }}[]" value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if value[choice.value] %} checked="checked"{% endif %}/> {{ choice.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded_options %}
```

Any improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In your `EntityType.php` file (this can be [auto-generated](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_form.html) based on your entities), you'll want an [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html) like the following:

```
$builder->add('item', 'entity' array(
    'class' => 'YourNameSpace:Item',
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->where('i.group = 1');
    }
);
```

Obviously you'll have to do some tweaking based on your specific schema and variable names. This also requires a bi-directional association between group and item. This also only adds the selector for group 1. You'd have to add another similar thing for your second group.

Comment: So first in my `EntityType` I have to get all groups and then call `$builder->add()` for each of them? Then another question - how to display such groups in twig, because, if I understand correctly, I'll have only _items_ in form?

Comment: OK. I've tried `$builder->add('item', 'entity', array())` for each group just changing group ID, but in form I just get last group items. Guess it's because of the same name `'item'`. Tried `$er->createQueryBuilder('i')->where('i.group = 1')->orWhere('i.group = 2')`, but then I just get all the items of these groups. Can't figure out how to group items in form view and output groups' names.

Comment: Was not the point to separate the items by groups? Not sure how that wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: The point is to display all the items in one entity form, but these items should be grouped. Like `<optgroup>` in select tag. I've found that it's possible with `group_by`, but couldn't achieve what I need :(